# Generated html code with javascript not working with jquery sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm generating a table each time a user presses a button. That table that gets generated should be sortable, although jquery's sortable is only working on tables being generated server side.

Generating tables:

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.addMenu', function() {
  $('.empty-table').after('<table class="account-subheader"><tbody class="connectedSortable"><tr><td colspan=5></td></tr></tbody> </table>');

  //$(".empty-table").append($(".account-subheader"));
});
</script>
```

Sortable function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
  $( ".connectedSortable" ).sortable({
     connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
     receive: function(event, ui) {
       $.ajax({
         // Some ajax calls
         },
         success: function(response) {
             if (response.status == "success") {
               console.log(response);
             } else {
               console.log(response);
             }
         }
       });
     }
  }).disableSelection();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `sortable` function after your generated HTML.
Try keeping the `sortable` function inside a javascript method and call that method from both `document.ready` and `click` event.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Called the sortable function on page load and when I generate the HTML table.